# JavaScript: Вытащить значения нескольких переменных из строки по шаблону

Tags: javascript, строки

Есть ли какая-нибудь функция в javascript, которая позволяет из заданной строки по заданному шаблону, прочитать значения нескольких переменных?

Например:

```
let str = "Цена: 50 руб., время: 14:35:47"
let params = str.getParams("Цена: %1% руб., время: %2%")
```

И в итоге чтобы получилось:

```
param[0] = "50"
param[1] = "14:35:47"
```

Я задаю шаблон, в котором указываю места откуда вытаскивать значения и функция вернет, например, массив с полученными значениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть "регулярные выражения", посмотрите.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

```js
const test_str = "Цена: 50 руб., время: 14:35:47"
const[all,...param] = test_str.match(/^Цена: (\d+) руб., время: (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$/)
console.log(param)
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!

Comment: @Alexander Lopatin,  Всегда рад. "Принимайте ответ" галочкой. Ответы почти одинаковые. У меня выражение чуть строже проверяет, у vsemozhebuty чуть мягче.

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй, самый простой способ — освоить [регулярные выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions). Например, в вашем случае можно использовать [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) и получить массив, в котором второй и третий элемент будут содержать нужные фрагменты строки:

```js
const str = "Цена: 50 руб., время: 14:35:47";
const params = str.match(/Цена: (\d+) руб., время: (\d+:\d+:\d+)/);

console.log(params);
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Ну я и думал, что это как-то через регулярные выражения, только не знал как найти решение)))